# Файловая система доступна только для чтения

Tags: ubuntu, файловая-система

Я установил ubuntu 19.04 рядом с Windows, разделив один жесткий диск на несколько разделов. Я точно знаю, что ubuntu стоит на /dev/sda10, а Windows на /dev/sda8

Я могу открыть /dev/sda8 и даже просматривать и копировать файлы, но я не могу ничего создать или изменить.

Кстати, этот раздел у меня монтирован в /media/fakeman/somename/
Права доступа я пытался выдать командой
`sudo chown -R fakeman:fakeman /media/fakeman/somename`
Но получал ту же ошибку `chown: изменение владельца '/media/fakeman/somename': Файловая система доступна только для чтения`

Как мне можно менять файлы в этом разделе, чтобы эти изменения были и в Windows, когда я туда зайду?

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего проблема в неправильно отключение Windows. Если не отключить гибернацию в Windows(в параметрах энергосбережения) то она не "отпускает" ваш диск и Linux не можен в него писать.
Может помочь ещё:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda8
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Отмонтируй sda8, например через утилиту DISKS - тапнуть раздел sda8 и нажать черный квадратик (отмонтировать).
2. Запустить терминал

   ```
   sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda8
   ```
3. Примонтировать sda8 - тапнуть на раздел sda8 и нажать черный треугольник (примонтировать).